# correct way to implement thread python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I am implement a simple simulator of soccer with python using threads and lock, the app works fine but I have doubts in the way that implement the thread it seems to me that the first team has an advantage because is executing first.

```
def jugar(Equipo1, Equipo2):
    # Busco las probabilidades de encajar por cada equipo
    prob_encajar_eq1 = Equipo1.probabilidad_encajar()
    prob_encajar_eq2 = Equipo2.probabilidad_encajar()

    def jugar_equipo1(defensa_rival):

        semaforo.acquire()
        if Equipo1.hacer_pases():
            Equipo1.shoot(defensa_rival)
        semaforo.release()

    def jugar_equipo2(defensa_rival):

        semaforo.acquire() 
        if Equipo2.hacer_pases():
            Equipo2.shoot(defensa_rival)
        semaforo.release() 


    hilo_equipo1 = threading.Thread(name = 'hilo_eq1', target = jugar_equipo1, args = (prob_encajar_eq2,))
    hilo_equipo2 = threading.Thread(name = 'hilo_eq2', target = jugar_equipo2, args = (prob_encajar_eq1,))


    hilo_equipo1.start()
    hilo_equipo2.start()

    hilo_equipo1.join()
    hilo_equipo2.join()
```

to make several attempts both teams, I do a cicle for a few seconds and inside the function jugar() which is the one that does the work with threads but here is were I have the doubts, because every time that jugar is executing the threads are declared again.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
cargar_informacion()    

eqA = Equipo(equipoA, ranking_eqA)
eqB = Equipo(equipoB, ranking_eqB)

probabilidades = porcenajes_ranking(ranking_eqA)
eqA.cargar_probabilidades(probabilidades)

probabilidades = porcenajes_ranking(ranking_eqB)
eqB.cargar_probabilidades(probabilidades)

starttime=time.time()
tiempo = 0
# creo la barra de progreso
bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=[
    progressbar.Percentage(),
    progressbar.Bar(),
], max_value=100).start()

# hacemos que el juego tarde aproximadamente 10seg en simularse.
while tiempo < 10:
    time.sleep(0.3 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 0.3))

    jugar(eqA,eqB)

    tiempo = time.time() - starttime
    bar += 2.8
bar.finish() # Para que finalice la barra de progreso

resultados_finales(eqA, eqB) # Mostramos el resultado final del partido.
```

Comment: I believe threads are not supposed to be completely fair, it's just an OS-level way for two tasks to execute concurrently. If you want complete fairness, maybe you should explicitly use a random number generator to assign time slots to the threads.

Comment: Also what are you asking? Do you want each execution of jugar to use the same two threads?

Comment: what I ask is that the cicle for repeat the plays and simulate the game has to be inside of jugar or leave it like that, because is not seems the correct way to me

Comment: That depends on your design goal; from what I currently see, you don't need to use threads, which means you probably shouldn't.

Comment: you are right but I have to use threads because is for a project in school

Comment: Generally useful for letting start multiple threads at the same time (or nealy the same time, system dependent) is a `threading.Barrier`